# Asp.net mvc, onload functions from Layout AND Webpage not working

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an asp.net mvc project and i have a problem with some javascripts functions.

I would like to execute functionA (from layout) & functionB (from a webpage) when the page is loading.

_Layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        ...
    </head>

    <body>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function functionA() {
                alert("Hello from Layout");
        }
        window.onload = functionA;
    </script>
</html>
```

Webpage.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "***";
}
<div>
...    
</div>
   
@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function functionB() {
        alert("Hello from WebPage");       
    }
    window.onload = functionB;
    </script>
}
```

window.onload is only working for the layout so when i'm going the the Webpage i can see "Hello from Layout" and not "Hello from Webpage".

Do you have an idea to perform both functions?

Thanks :) .

Comment: You're reassigning `window.onload` to a different function. Take a look at [the DOMContentLoaded event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) for more info on the proper way to attach a handler to this event.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
      myFunction();
}
```